# jQuery form submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, href

i have several forms within my website that each have the submit button as a href. 
all my a's are caught through jQuery
`$("a").live("click", function() {`
inside that area there is a big switch statement that depending on the id of the a different actions will be taken.  For all formSubmit ids, the parent is retrieved.

    `case "formSubmit":
    a.parents("form:first").submit();`

i want to catch all the forms, so i try this...

`$("form").live("submit", function() {`

But when i execute that, i test it out with putting the forms action as some alert so i know if its executing its own action or i am overriding it.  I am not overriding it.  The form is also added dynamically with jQuery doing a $.post call, then taking the output and filling the main content area.

If i use ...

`$("form").submit(function() {`


The forms will NOT be captured either.  Not the forms that were during the creation of the document or the ones added during the users time on the site. Any suggestsions? (Had to edit due to super poor english skills!).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.submit()` simply triggers the submit **event**. To actually submit the form, you want the DOM's `.submit()`:

```
a.parents("form:first")[0].submit();
```

Side note: use `.closest("form")` rather than `.parents("form:first")`

Comment: Why closest rather than parents? And let me test your solution!

Comment: after trying `var form = a.closest("form");
                            form[0].submit();` and '$("form").live("submit", function() {' or '$("form").submit( function() {' The form is simply not being overriden.  The alert statement is still triggering (it is the native form action) but the override is not happening!

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your problem. I think what you want is to prevent the browser's default action from occuring. For that you need to return false from the event handler. The reason .live() isn't working is that live works by handling the event once it bubbles up to the document level. By that time it is too late. The simplest solution is to use .submit(), but rebind it to each form that is added. The other alternative is to use a jQuery plugin called livequery, but avoid it if you can.